# Get post id within comments loop

Tags: php, loop, comments, post-meta

I have a custom comments loop on my `author.php` page. I am trying to get the post id so that I can echo the permalink for the post that the comment belongs to. Also so I can echo some post meta custom fields.

This is what my loop looks like now -

```
<?php
$object = get_queried_object();
$authorID = get_queried_object()->ID;
$author_email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $authorID );
$postid = get_queried_object()->post->ID;
$args = array(
    'user_id' => $authorID,
    'post_id' => $postid,
); 

// The Query
$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments_query->query( $args );

// Comment Loop
if ( $comments ) {
    foreach ( $comments as $comment ) { ?>
```

I tried place a normal post loop within this but things got weird. The part I need the post meta for is this --

```
<div class="full-divs">
    <strong>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">
            View 
            <?php 
                $property_address = get_post_meta( 
                    get_the_ID(),
                    'imic_property_site_address',
                    true
                ); 
                echo $property_address; 
            ?>
         </a>
     </strong>
 </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that it might be easier to use `get_comments()` here, since it's defined as:

```
function get_comments( $args = '' ) {
    $query = new WP_Comment_Query;
    return $query->query( $args );
}
```

If you need the *comment url*, within your `foreach` comment loop, you can use:

```
$comment_url =  esc_url( get_comment_link( $comment ) );
```

You can also get the *post id* from the `$comment` object with:

```
$post_id = $comment->comment_post_ID;
```

then you can use that to retrieve the *custom post meta*:

```
$property_address = get_post_meta( $post_id ,'imic_property_site_address',true);
```

To get the corresponding `post permalink`

```
$post_url = esc_url( get_permalink( $post_id ) );
```

Comment: I couldn't comment last night due to the phone issue, but I think you understood the question perfectly. ;-)

Comment: If Im using my existing loop do I use it like this `   $object = get_queried_object();
        $authorID = get_queried_object()->ID;
        $author_email = get_the_author_meta( 'user_email', $authorID );
$post_id = $comment->comment_post_ID;
        $args = array(
            'user_id' => $authorID,
        );` cause right now its not doing anything when using $post_id for the permalink and custom field

Comment: if you want to get the post ID from each comment in the `foreach` loop, then you should place  `$post_id = $comment->comment_post_ID;` within the `foreach` loop. @mygm26

Answer (score 1):

There is no `$post` property in `get_queried_object()`. `get_queried_object()` returns info about the current author when viewing the author archive page. You can do a `var_dump()` to check what `get_queried_object()` return

```
var_dump( get_queried_object() );
```

This is why your code fails. I am really not sure what you need to achieve here, but any post info can be accessed by using the main query object

- `$wp_query->posts` returns an array of post objects. This is the posts that will be displayed by the loop
- `$wp_query->post` returns the first post object of the loop, the same post object as `$post` before the loop

I probably think this is what you are after